HTTP URL Redirect for a Proxy server
I am trying to use a HTTP redirect rules to redirect a URL to an appended version. I want to redirect from /test/go to /test/go/#/XXXXX where XXXXX is a random page name in a reverse proxy server.
This what I have tried to no avail:
 RewriteEngine On

`RedirectMatch ^/test/view/(.*)$ https://it.joes.com:8443/test/view/#/$1

 ProxyPass /test/view https://it.joes.com:8443/test/view
 ProxyPassReverse /test/view https://it.joes.com:8443/test/view 

Using /test/view/ in the URL should go to /mobius/view/#/XXXXXX but only the '#/' characters are being currently appended to the URL and application throws an error and stalls during page loading.
Any direction that can be provided is greatly appreciated.

The URL fragment is never sent to the server.  The # symbol and everything after it cannot be used in rewrite rules.  What you are asking to do is not possible.
You could make it work if you changed it to a ? and made XXXXXX a query parameter.
